# Can I delete entries from POA table in Dynamics CRM 365 on-prem?

Tags: dynamics-crm, case, contacts, dynamics-crm-365, unified-service-desk

We are using D365 on-prem, in our business process we are supposed to log 4000 cases and around 2000 contacts in CRM. Along with this, the entries in POA table are keep growing and they are now around 17 millions. Now from last 3 to 4 days we are facing slow CRM response in browser as well as in Unified Service Desk (USD).

Any idea how can I increase the performance in such environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cleanup the POA table for orphaned records.  Based on your security need you might have designed the concepts of ownership/assignment/sharing which leads to POA table growth.

A good post to start: [Lessons Learned Deleting 312 Million Records From CRM’s PrincipalObjectAccess Table](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/01/lessons-learned-deleting-312-million.html?m=1)

Next thing is running SQL profiler & finding the missing index. Adding this index will definitely improve the search performance. Don’t forget that over-indexing will impact the create/update operations.